# How to create a slide up+ right arrow animation for CSS Feature Box?

Tags: css

Can anybody help me get an idea of how it is done? I want to make something similar to the ones at [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgzsh.jpg)https://www.brookfield.com/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="description">
        <h1>Real Estate</h1>
        <p>As one of the largest investros in real estate....</p>
        <a href="url">Learn more &rarr;</a>
    </div>
</div>
<style>
    #container {
        background-image: url("image_url");
        background-size: cover;
        height: 80%;
        width: 25%;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        padding: 2%;
    }
    
    #description {
        margin-top: 95%;
        color: white;
    }
    
    p {
        font-size: 120%;
    }
    
    a {
        color: blue;
        font-size: 120%;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks @Jigar K! What about the CSS animation feature? Such as the right arrow to Learn More transition and the slide up feature of the content box? Thanks again!

Comment: What type of animation you want........

Comment: For slide up we can use translate() or margin top,left, bottom,down methods